# Unable to write Bitmap into SD Card

Tags: android, android-sdcard, fileoutputstream

I am trying to write a Bitmap into SD Card(as Png file), Find below the Code

```
File file = new File(getExternalFilesDir(null), "DemoFile.png");
OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(file);
Log.d("JS", "File name -> " + file.getAbsolutePath());
//File name -> /mnt/sdcard/Android/data/com.pocmodule/files/DemoFile.png
bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 90, os); //here bmp is of type 'Bitmap'
os.close();
```

But I do not see the file 'DemoFile.png' being created in SD Card. Let alone the Png File, I do not even see the directory 'com.pocmodule' available in the SD Card.

Am I missing anything in my code?

Comment: any exception or a log? Maybe you don't have the permission for writing?

Comment: "But I do not see the file 'DemoFile.png' being created in SD Card. Let alone the Png File, I do not even see the directory 'com.pocmodule' available in the SD Card" -- how are you looking for it? DDMS' File Explorer? **`adb shell ls`**? Something else? Bear in mind that the path that you have in your comment is not necessarily where the file actually resides in the filesystem, for Android 4.2+, as part of Android's support for multiple accounts per device.

Comment: @CommonsWare, I mount my Device(with USB debugging mode selected) and explored the directory. Never used DDMS (or) adb shell :(. Would going through DDMS (or) adb will be helpful?(FYI, I am using Android Studio). "Bear in mind that the path that you have in your comment is not necessarily where the file actually resides in the filesystem, for Android 4.2" -- If the Path do not represent the exact path in file system, then how do I verify the created file?

Comment: @Zielony, I do not get any exception

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I mount my Device(with USB debugging mode selected) and explored the directory

That does not explore the filesystem. It explores what is known to `MediaStore`.

So, first, call `flush()`, then `getFD().sync()`, on your `FileOutputStream` before you call `close()` on it, to ensure that all bytes are written to disk.

Then, use `MediaScannerConnection` and `scanFile()` to teach `MediaStore` about your file.

This may still require you to do some sort of "refresh" in your desktop OS's file explorer window to see the change, or possibly even unplug and re-plug in your device, due to the desktop OS possibly caching "directory" contents.

Comment: Hi @CommonsWare, I am curious about this MediaScanner. Say for ex; when we write a File to a Path in Laptop(Say for example using a Java Program), The file is immediately available in the Path specified. We do not have this concept of MediaStore. But why in Android we need to teach the MediaStore?. I really do not want this File to be visible to the user(which they can view through Gallery app) in their device. Just want to access the file from inside my Android application. Not sure if I am missing some basics. Any link or info should be helpful

Comment: @Raj: "We do not have this concept of MediaStore" -- actually, you do. The protocol spoken over the USB cable is the Media Transfer Protocol (MTP). What Android serves over MTP is what is indexed by `MediaStore`. When the desktop OS *sends* a file over MTP, I suspect that it is indexed immediately by the `MediaStore`. "I really do not want this File to be visible to the user" -- then why are you putting it on external storage? The **definition** of external storage is "stuff that is visible to the user".

Comment: Thanks @CommonsWare ; that really helps me to understand more. For your question - "then why are you putting it on external storage", I am actually trying to use Expansion File(the '.obb' file in my case is a Zip file containing multiple png image files) ; I am trying to retrieve these Images(.png file) from '.obb' file, do some optimization and put it back in the same '.obb' file. So initially thought it does not make any sense to teach the MediaStore. But as u have said if this is related to USB Transfer ; then teaching the MediaStore becomes necessary

Answer (score 1):

Thanks @CommonsWare for the help. I finally have the Png file available in SD Card :). For anyone who wants to know the working code, Please find below

```
File file = new File(getExternalFilesDir(null), "DemoFile.png");
FileOutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(file);
    Log.d("JS", "File name -> " + file.getAbsolutePath());
    //Here 'bmp' is of type Bitmap
    bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 90, os); 
    os.flush();
    os.getFD().sync();
    os.close();

    MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(this,
            new String[]{file.toString()}, null,
            new MediaScannerConnection.OnScanCompletedListener() {
                public void onScanCompleted(String path, Uri uri) {
                    Log.i("ExternalStorage", "Scanned " + path + ":");
                    Log.i("ExternalStorage", "-> uri=" + uri);
                }
            });
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32127869/cant-create-anything-on-sdcard-or-load-an-image-from-it  I have same problem but couldnt do any thing I tried a lot but still cant write any thing on sd